# If a, b, c are non coplanar unit vectors..

Tags: vectors

Such that $ a \times (b \times c) =\frac{ b + c}{\sqrt{2}}$  prove the angle between a, b is 3/4pi.

I really don't want open the thing with vector so i cross both sidrs first with b and then with a I'll get

$ c \times ( b \times (a \times (b \times c))) = a \times b \times  a \times b \times c = \frac{a \times b \times c}{\sqrt{2}}$

Since cross product is unique

$ a \times b \times a = \frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}$

upon dotting both sides with a and rearranging i get the wrong answer ie a = 0. Where am i going wrong?

Continuing to error -

$- a \cdot (a \times a \times b)  = a \times b \cdot (a \times a) $
(a. bx c = c.axb with c = axb)

Comment: You know $a$ x $b = |a||b|\cdot \sin(\theta)$

Comment: @Fightclub1995, on the last one? I'll get the same answer for a x b x a ans a x a x b  : (. One of them gives the right answer though . but i tried a.a x (a x b) with a.bxc = c.axb with c =axb. It doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the rule for [triple vector product](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorTripleProduct.html):
$$
a\times(b\times c)=b(a\cdot c)-c(a\cdot b)=b\cos\gamma - c\cos\beta,
$$
where $\gamma$ and $\beta$ are the angles formed by $a$ with $c$ and $b$.

Comparing that with $a\times(b\times c)=(b+c)/\sqrt2$ we get then:
$$
\cos\gamma={1\over\sqrt2},\quad \cos\beta=-{1\over\sqrt2}.
$$

Comment: That was easier than expected : /. Well, is there something wrong with what i did though?

Comment: Nvm i got figured it out